# If $\lambda$ is in spectrum of bounded linear operator $A$, then $\lambda^n$ is in spectrum of $A^n$.

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, spectral-theory

If $\lambda$ is in spectrum of $A$ then for all $n \in N$, $\lambda^n$ is in spectrum of $A^n$.

I try to solve this but I could only solve in the case point spectrum assuming $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue. But I know that it is incomplete.

Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply applying the definitions, you want to prove that if $\lambda I - A$ is not invertible, then $\lambda^n I - A^n$ is not invertible. Contrapositively: if $\lambda^n I - A^n$ has an inverse, then so does $\lambda I - A$.

Progress can be made just by generalizing the usual factorization
$$
   x^n - y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}y + \dots + x y^{n-2} + y^{n-1})
$$
to a factorization of linear operators
$$
   \lambda^n I - A^n = (\lambda I - A)(\lambda^{n-1}I + \lambda^{n-2}A + \dots + \lambda A^{n-2} + A^{n-1})
$$
which is easy to check just by distributing and cancelling. (Note that $\lambda I$ always commutes with $A$.)

From here, it's easy to take an inverse of $\lambda^n I - A^n$ and use it to construct an inverse of $\lambda I - A$.

Comment: Note that $\lambda I - A$ and the sum (call it $B$) commute too. Since $(\lambda I - A)B$ is invertible, $\lambda I - A$ is surjective. Since $B(\lambda I - A)$ is invertible, $\lambda I - A$ is injective.

Comment: My own idea was to write down the left and right inverses specifically. That's equivalent, but it's probably important to be aware that just a one-sided inverse is not enough here.

Comment: I wrote the comment because I couldn't figure out how to write the inverse explicitly. The only way I could think to do it was to use the inverse of the sum, but I couldn't see an easier way to show that sum is invertible than to use the method in my first comment. How would you write the inverse explicitly?

Comment: We don't need to invert the sum. If $X$ is the inverse of $\lambda^n I - A^n$, then $(\lambda^n I - A^n)X = I$, so $(\lambda I - A)BX = I$, and the right inverse is $BX$. Similarly, $XB(\lambda I - A) = X(\lambda^n I  - A^n) = I$, and the left inverse is $XB$. (I believe we can now conclude that $BX = XB$ and we have a two-sided inverse, right?)