# if $\lambda^n I - A^n$ has an inverse, then so does $\lambda I - A$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Based on this question:[$UV$ is invertible if and only if $U$ and $V$ are both invertible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4818925/uv-is-invertible-if-and-only-if-u-and-v-are-both-invertible)

How to modify this wrong statement? Actually, I want to apply that statement to prove the following question:

If $\lambda$ is in spectrum of $A$ then for all $n \in N$, $\lambda^n$ is in spectrum of $A^n$.

Here we need to factor it:
$\lambda^n I - A^n = (\lambda I - A)(\lambda^{n-1}I + \lambda^{n-2}A + \dots + \lambda A^{n-2} + A^{n-1}),$ which is easy to check just by distributing and cancelling. (Note that $\lambda I$ always commutes with $A$.)

If $\lambda^n I - A^n$ has an inverse, then so does $\lambda I - A$.

Update: our statement: Let $U, V$ be linear operator on normed space $X$. Assume that $UV=VU$. Then $UV$ is invertible if and only if $U$ and $V$ are both invertible.

Comment: Note that in the question you linked in the linked question, we also have $UV=VU$.

Comment: For the question in the post, I think you forgot the note $\lambda I$ commutes with $A$. This implies that $ (\lambda^{n-1}I + \lambda^{n-2}A + \dots + \lambda A^{n-2} + A^{n-1})$ and $(\lambda I - A)$ commutes, and you can thus construct the inverse of $(\lambda I - A)$ assumed the inverse of $ (\lambda^{n-1}I + \lambda^{n-2}A + \dots + \lambda A^{n-2} + A^{n-1})$.

Comment: @Tri But what is the inverse of $(\lambda^{n-1}I+\dots A^{n-1})$? That is a problem... So we can only get the left inverse and right inver of $(\lambda I-A)$ as comments.

Comment: @Hermi sorry, I copied the wrong one. I meant the inverse of $\lambda^n I -A^n$ - you can call it $B$ and then $X=(\lambda^{n-1}I + \lambda^{n-2}A + \dots + \lambda A^{n-2} + A^{n-1})B$ is the inverse of $\lambda I-A$. We don't need to find the inverse of $(\lambda^{n-1}I + \lambda^{n-2}A + \dots + \lambda A^{n-2} + A^{n-1})$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct lemma is this:

> Let $X$ be a vector space and let $U,V$ be endomorphisms on $X$ such that $UV = VU$.  Then $UV$ is invertible if and only if $U$ and $V$ are both invertible.

(This can be generalized a little more, but this suffices for the current situation you find yourself in)

Comment: And instead of $\mathrm{End}(X)$ we can work in any ring.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Right.  In fact, I suppose we can work in any monoid.

Comment: What do you mean $U, V$ be endomorphisms? Can you please write the statement in sense of functional analysis? Let $X$ be a normed space or Banach space and $U, V$ be linear operator? Thank you! Also, if it is possible, can you please write a proof of that?

Comment: So the statement is that let $U, V$ be linear operator on normed space $X$. Assume that $UV=VU$. Then $UV$ is invertible if and only if $U$ and $V$ are both invertible?

Comment: For one side proof: assume that $U$ and $V$ are invertible, then the inverse of $UV$ is $S:=V^{-1}U^{-1}$. Indeed, $UVS=I=S(UV)$. But assume that $UV$ is invertible, how to show $U$ and $V$ are both invertible?

Comment: @Hermi Let $S$ be the inverse of $UV$.  Then $U(VS) = (UV)S = I = S(UV) = S(VU) = (SV)U$.  As $U$ has both a left inverse and a right inverse, it is invertible.

Comment: @BrianMoehring But for the definition of inverse operator, we say $U$ is invertible if there exists operator $S$ so that $SU=US=I$. But here our left inverse is not same as the right inverse. How to deal with that?

Comment: @Hermi You should study some algebra.  A lot of these issues are standard exercises in a linear algebra or group theory class.  In particular, if $S_LU=US_R = I$ is a two-sided identity element, then $$S_L = S_LI=S_L(US_R)=(S_LU)S_R = IS_R=S_R.$$  As I said in the previous comment, "as $U$ has both a left inverse and a right inverse, it is invertible"

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thank you!